# How can I detect undefined symbols in a binary/library?

Tags: binary, shared-libraries, linkage, undefined-symbol

Is there a tool that takes a binary (executable) or a library and, looking also into any shared library dependencies, finds and lists any undefined symbols (even if they are not used)? Any practical way of finding this?

Comment: try linking it into an executable?

Comment: The executable can refer to symbols that are in shared libs that were forgotten when linking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using *nix, and symbols have not been stripped, using 'nm' will help.

```
# nm lib-or-binary-name
U strcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

The 'U' means undefined, and if it is satisfied somewhere, that will be noted after the @.

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for, thanks! BTW, `-u` options gives you undefined symbols already and `-C` demangles directly

Comment: I found there are ‘B’ 'T' 'V' besides 'U', what means 'B' 'T' 'V'? Many thanks.