# How to link to location of a newly installed library

Tags: c, linker

I am trying to use `pcre2` in a program, and I have compiled it using:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ configure; make; make install
```

Everything configured/installed fine, and the last lines of the output were:

```
./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/pcre2.h '/usr/local/include'
./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libpcre2-8.pc libpcre2-posix.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
$
```

Now to compile a program which includes `<pcre2.h>` I am using:

```
$ gcc pcretest.c -lpcre -o pcretest
```

However, I get the following linking error which I assume is because it cannot find the `pcre` library:

```
$ gcc pcretest.c -lpcre -o pcretest
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcre2_compile_8", referenced from:
      _pcre_compile_pattern in pcretest-7b4796.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How would I (1) 'include' the `pcre2` library, and (2) find where that library (or file) is located to include that path?

Comment: "I get the following linking error which I assume is because it cannot find the pcre library" - No, the error means that linker has **found** the library. But that library doesn't contain the needed symbol (`_pcre2_compile_8`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev hm, I see. how can I got about debugging/fixing that then?

Comment: You could use `nm` to check symbols in the library you have. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271363/how-can-i-detect-undefined-symbols-in-a-binary-library